# How to solve ntdll.dll!RtlpLogHeapFailure() in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c, visual-studio, heap-memory, ntdll

I am currently working on an AI project. It's about that puzzle you need to move the board pieces numbered from 1 to 8 (and the empty space is labelled as 0) in order to let it sorted at the end.
However I got a weird problem when I try to debug it.

```
int CreateNewState(State *parent, Action action) {
State *newState;

    if (!(newState = (State*)malloc(sizeof(State)))) // <<<< Error
       return 0;
...

   // Populate my newState
   newState->parent = parent;
   newState->matrix = CreateMatrix();
...
   // Insert my newState in the Queue
   Insert(newState, myMode);
}


void Insert(State *state, Mode mode) {
   State *aux;

    if (IsEmpty()) {
        myQueue->firstState = state;
        myQueue->numberOfElements++;
    }
    else {
        aux = myQueue->firstState;

        switch (mode)
        {
            // Breadth First Search
            case BFS:
                while (aux->next != NULL) {
                   aux = aux->next;
                }
                aux->next = state;
                myQueue->numberOfElements++;
                break;
           ...

        }
    }
}
```

In the specified Error comment, when I call the CreateNewState() function for the second time, the Debugger stops and popups:

> AIProject_Puzzle.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

I tried to bring you guys some additional information in the Call Stack when this error occurs:

> ntdll.dll!RtlReportCriticalFailure()
>       ntdll.dll!RtlpHeapHandleError()
>       ntdll.dll!RtlpLogHeapFailure()
>       ntdll.dll!RtlpAllocateHeap()
>       ntdll.dll!RtlAllocateHeap()
>       ucrtbased.dll!00007ff9b582c4da()
>       ucrtbased.dll!00007ff9b582c27d()
>       ucrtbased.dll!00007ff9b582f34f()
>       ucrtbased.dll!00007ff9b582fdde()
>     AIProject_Puzzle.exe!CreateNewState(state * parent=0x000000c05c273520, action action=DOWN)

I know it might be a Heap corruption so, what I really need it is a clue in order to solve this.
I am using Visual Studio Community 2015, VisualC++.
This error is making me sick. Please could anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, the error is likely somewhere else. Like in `CreateMatrix` or in some other functions accidentally writing outside the matrix.

Comment: @BoPersson Indeed, I had a deep look into it, it was on `CreateMatrix` I was not allocating the necessary memory. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out, dude.